# Get .NET version by Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net

Recently I create a project with electron, but I found some features like Bluetooth not work on Windows. I decide to add .NET for Windows version and use [electron-cgi](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/electron-cgi) to connect .NET program.

In some case, users didn't install .NET on PC, and I want to remind users to install .NET in my application. How to get .NET version or whether installed thought by nodejs?

Comment: Theres a article by msft about this topic. give it a read! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-detect-whether-the-net-framework-3-0-is-installed?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: We might struggle with this if electron is using chromium and chrome is dropping user agent detection - if chromium follow suit...

Comment: @Aaron Thank you, but I follow the document and get  navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET CLR [0-9.]+/g) == null. I am sure about my environment installed .NET